# How to control custom button on ngx-plyr

Tags: angular, typescript, plyr

THIS ORIGINAL POST WAS EDITED

[image]

I'm trying to create a custom control on ngx-plyr, i copied the controls from here [controls.md](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/CONTROLS.md) but instead specifying the control inside `plyrOptions` like the docs said, i'm creating element inside `component.html`.

The reason i do that is because i need other buttons, which have custom function. I don't if there's a way to create custom funtion inside `controls` property of `plyrOptions` or not, so right now i stick with this setup.

Here's my custom button

```
  <div class="plyr__progress" style="width:70%;">
    <input data-plyr="seek" type="range" [nbTooltip]="remaining"
      nbTooltipPlacement="top" nbTooltipStatus="basic" [max]="duration" min="0"step=".000001" [value]="time" aria-label="Seek"
      (input)="seeked($event.target.value)">
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 15px;" class="plyr__time plyr__time--current" aria-label="Current time">{{remaining}}
  </div>
  <div class="plyr__time plyr__time--duration" aria-label="Duration">{{ durationString }}</div>
  <button [nbPopover]="templateRef" nbTooltip="Repeat Section" nbTooltipPlacement="top" nbTooltipStatus="basic"
    nbPopoverPlacement="top" type="button" class="plyr__control">
    <img width="16px" src="/assets/icon/repeat.svg" />
    <span role="tooltip" class="plyr__tooltip">Repeat Section</span>
  </button>
```

there are actually 1 custom button that i wanted to handle, but since all of the controls are custom, so i need to set value and functions to each control such as play, pause etc.

right now what didn't work is changing the time by seeking or drag the range slider handle, i specified the value of video time using `timeupdate` event like this

```
  plyr.player.on('timeupdate', () => {
    this.time = plyr.player.currentTime;
    this.remaining = this.parse(plyr.player.duration - plyr.player.currentTime);
  })
```

and for changing the time from range slider input using this function

```
  seeked(e) {
    this.plyr.forEach(plyr => {
      plyr.player.on('playing', ()=>{
        this.time = e;
        plyr.player.currentTime = e;
      })
    });
  }
```

but that didn't work as i expected, it didn't play the video based on the time that i selected. did anyone knows why?

Comment: Sorry its very hard to understand why your trying to create custom button, when all controls are made available in Documentation (https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-plyr). I can see from your post your trying to use the `seek` `seeking` and `timeUpdated` events, but there all available out of the box. Can you kindly share your code on stackblitz so I can understand the problem?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-plyr-yxgk7d here i recreate that, try changing time using custom progress bar below to see what i mean what's not working

Answer (score 1):

Okay the reason why it didn't play from the time you `seeked` to, is because you were setting the `currentTime` to `e`. When debugging it, it logged `e` as a `string` and so you need parse the value.

```ts
  // Code based on your stackblitz example
  seeked(e) {
    // This logs as string.
    console.log(typeof e);

    // This logs as number.
    console.log(typeof parseFloat(e));

    this.plyr.forEach(plyr =>{
      plyr.player.once('timeupdate', ()=>{
        plyr.player.currentTime = parseFloat(e);
        plyr.player.play();
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: how silly i am, i forgot that the value was a string LoL, ok i'll try to implement it

Comment: i can jump to the time that i want, but it doesn't play automatically, even if i click play it just start glitching

Comment: after messing round, i change `on` event to `once` it is working and also calls `play` function after the time change, still glitchy but it is playing